# Resize iOS tableviewcell contaning several views

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, resize

I'm looking for a way to resize a `tableView` cell with a more complex layout.

To simplify the description of the problem the `tableview` cell consists of three views. One view that defines the "background" of the cell and two additional views (each of them with a height 45% of the background cell. 
One of these additional views is tagged to the top of the background view the other one to be bottom.
If the user taps on the tableview cell it should shrink in a way that only the top view is visible and after an additional user tap it should resize to its full size again.

The user tap is handled by the function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

and the resizing is done by

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

Unfortunately, after shrinking the tableview cell, both addition views are displayed with half of their original hight.

```swift
    var selectedCell = -1

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if (selectedCell != indexPath.row)
        {
            selectedCell = indexPath.row
        }
        else {
            selectedCell = -1
        }
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if (indexPath.row == selectedCell)
        {
            return 65
        }
        else {

            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }
    }
```

I'm now looking for a way to change the code in a way, that after shrinking only the upper view is visible. 
[Example picture of the fully visible cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61kDd.png)
In the example picture, after shrinking the tableview cell should only display the red view.

Thanks in advance
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that when the cell is shrunk, your views (since their sizes are defined relative to parent's size) also gets shrunk and are visible with half size. They are not really gone/hidden from the view. What you need is to hide/remove them from the view.

It looks from your description that you are using plain constraints to achieve this. This can be done by just using constraints but its a lot more work. So I will mention two ways to get this done:

1. Using just constraints

When the user taps your cell, you need to make the height of the bottom view 0. Also, if you do not want the middle 10% part to show when the cell shrinks, you would need to create an additional constraint from the bottom of the top view to the bottom of the `contentView` of the cell. Similarly, your bottom view will also have two height constraints, one for 45% and one for 0. 
The idea is to have both these constraints at the same time but with different priorities. The initial constraint will have higher priority and the other one will have a lower priority. Although these constraints will be contradictory, iOS will take the higher priority one to render the view.

Next, you would need to toggle the active property of the higher priority constraint on user tap which will in turn let iOS use the lower priority constraint to render the view.

2. Use stackview:

iOS 9 introduced stack view which is a helper view. It basically, handles constraints for you, at least some part of it. When you hide one view from the stack view's children, stack view will automatically make the height of that view to be 0. read up more about vertical stack view and you will get the idea.